# Office 2011 - Folders on Mac OS X Server network share not visible during save

Tags: macos, finder, ms-office

I have a computer I'm servicing running OS X Mavericks and Office 2011.  I open Finder, navigate to a network share (under Shared on the left pane), and see a shared server (shows up as a Mac mini picture), click on it and see 2 folders, go in one I need into and see files.  I then switch over to Word 2011, go to Save As, and navigate to the same shared server on the left, and see the folders there, but when I go into that folder, it is blank.  If I click on the shared server on the left again, it doesn't show me either of the shared folders.

What is going on here?

I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting the share, restarting the Mac, Office is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. To fix it I renamed my Library->Application Support->Microsoft->Office folder to "Office Backup", allowing the program to create a new folder upon opening. After reopening, the issue was fixed.

Be sure to copy over any template files you had created (such as an updated normal.dotm file for word) from the Backup folder to the new one once you have confirmed the issue has been fixed.